# How to uninstall SuperManager

Tags: applications, uninstallation

I installed the [SuperManager app](https://market.android.com/details?id=gpc.myweb.hinet.net.TaskManager) and every time I try to uninstall it it just stays there. Has anyone experienced that and found a solution?

Comment: Do you mean SuperUser?

Comment: No, "Super Manager" by gpc

Comment: What method have you used to try to uninstall it?  Have you rebooted your phone since uninstalling?

Answer (score 1):

This might seem like running in circles, but try downloading and installing the "Uninstaller" app http://www.appbrain.com/app/uninstaller/com.rhythm.hexise.uninst and use that to remove Super Manager.
I can't speak on Super Manager itself, but I know I've run into problems with not being able to uninstall things before, and this app has helped out.  Then, once Super Manager is gone, you can just uninstall the uninstaller app and you're no worse for the wear.
Good luck!